# card_swiper cause the widget and statics imgs redraw [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am currently using card swiper in flutter so I give a list of strings where I use the string with the paths of the files the project has to show the images but I just realized that it redraws the widget when I use autoplay this is my code:

```dart
class _NewsSwiperState extends State<_NewsSwiper> {
  final List<String> imgs = ['assets/img/1.jpg', 'assets/img/2.jpg', 'assets/img/3.png', 'assets/img/login-screen-background.jpg'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Swiper(
      itemCount: imgs.length,
      itemHeight: double.infinity,
      itemWidth: double.infinity,
      layout: SwiperLayout.TINDER,
      autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
      autoplay: true,
      loop: false,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Image.asset(
        imgs[index],
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Try on a stateless widget

Comment: doesn't work, the issue continues, it seems as if reloading the image, but I don't understand why, is a statelesswidget,I invoke it inside of a stateful @KaushikChandru

Comment: Is it out of the screen and then comes inside the screen on auto play?

Comment: Sorry, I believe I have not explained well. I mean, currently is a private statelesswidget, so the swiper widget has a property called autoplay, that cause a effect like the static image is reloading or the entire widget is readrawing (it's not what I'm looking for
). Could the problem be that I call my stateless widget inside a stateful widget and that causes the problem I mentioned?

Comment: No calling a stateless widget inside a stateful widget doesn't cause a problem, but maybe the way its written can cause a problem. Since you are using asset images it shouldn't even show a loading for you. Can you post your entire code please?